# "Truffle unbox react" Not Working Properly

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract, react

I am facing problems running the basic official setup of react and truffle. Here's what I did:

```
truffle init
truffle unbox react
truffle develop
truffle(develop)> compile
truffle(develop)> migrate
```

Then in another window:

```
npm run start
```

However the browser window containing `http://localhost:3000/` that appears shows the following:

[image]

In the browser JS console, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to fetch
    at Object.InvalidResponse (bundle.js:45023)
    at bundle.js:34169
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:9904
    at completeRequest (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:9955)
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:678
    at replenish (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:1198)
    at iterateeCallback (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:1188)
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:1163
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:9832
    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:9928
```

Any idea what is happening?